# Slow email sending from php-fpm

Tags: php, linux, email, sendmail, msmtp

I am using **msmtp** for sending emails from my sites, so i have set variable **sendmail_path** to **/usr/bin/msmtp** in php config file.

It works, but...
I found a significant time difference between sending emails using php function `mail()` and sending from terminal, although it is one program.

It takes about a second when sending from terminal directly, and 5-10 seconds from php.

I have tested it a lot of times. It is always much longer.

Can anybody say why it is so, and what can I do to stop my sites hangs when it sends email.

Comment: I don't know where the timing difference comes from, but using a queue is usually the way to go with emails. You then have a different process getting mails from the queue and sending them, which allows to avoid halting.

Comment: 5s delay may indicate unresponsive DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`.